# Struggling to get data out of POST - going in circles.?

Tags: php, post, xmlhttprequest

Really struggling here and I am sure it's something very simple. I am trying to upload some data from a mobile APP using xmlhttp and a PHP backend.

Have tried first using the following JavaScript;

```html
 <script>
            function sendData()
             {
                
                 var xmlhttp = new XHRObject();                              
                 
                 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                 {
                     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {                    
                    xmlhttp.responsetext will have what is sent back - use Print_R in php
                    document.getElementById('ResponseDiv').innerHTML = "Entry Posted";          
                    }
                 }     
           
                 var d = new Date();
                 var n = d.toLocaleString(d);
                 var uid = intel.xdk.device.uuid;     
                               
                 var postdata = '{';
                 postdata += '"SBP_VehicleReg": "' + document.getElementById('VehicleReg').value + '"';
                 postdata += ',"SBP_Uuid": "' + uid + '"';
                 postdata += ',"SBP_PostedDate": "' + n + '"';
                 postdata += ',"SBP_Category": "' + document.getElementById('Category').value + '"';
                 postdata += ',"SBP_Details": "' + document.getElementById('Details').value + '"';
                 postdata += '}';   
                 
                 xmlhttp.open("POST","http://sxxxx.co.uk/SBPostPost.php", false);
                 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
                 
              
                 xmlhttp.send(postdata);
             }
        </script>
```

....Using Debug I get the following showing as POSTed; (Which to me looks ok)

```html
Request URL:http://sxxxx.co.uk/SBPostPost.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Content-type:multipart/form-data
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:58889
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/Users/Phils/AppData/Local/XDK/xdk-scratchdir/e14eb410-7cf2-4bed-ba25-515e6df98e8c/platforms/ios/www/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A4345d Safari/600.1.4
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:4F9909BD-1710-45D3-874E-7CE5AB421AA8
Request Payload    view source
{SBP_VehicleReg:abcdefghij, SBP_Uuid:A86780BE-4F09-4428-8BF6-05A59B422126,…}
SBP_Category: "Opt1"
SBP_Details: "details of the POST"
SBP_PostedDate: "15/09/2015 12:44:33"
SBP_Uuid: "A86780BE-4F09-4428-8BF6-05A59B422126"
SBP_VehicleReg: "abcdefghij"
Response Headers
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:513
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 15 Sep 2015 11:44:30 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

BUT when I try to get the fields out - using the following PHP - I get nothing; 
Have tried all sorts;

```
    *$headers = getallheaders();
    while (list($header, $value) = each($headers)) {
    echo "$header: $value<br>\n";*
```

This Responds with the Headers Ok

```
*if ($headers["Content-Type"] == "multipart/form-data") {
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }*
```

This responds with 'Success'

```
  *foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
echo "Param: $param_name; Value: $param_val<br />\n";
}*
```

BUT this gives nothing;

```
 *echo $_POST['SBP_Uuid'];*
```

And this gives 'Undefined Variable SBP_Uuid

Any ideas??

Phil

Comment: can you try `echo print_r($_REQUEST, true);` and post the result here ?

Comment: Hi Tismon - tried that and just got a response of Array
(
)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `var_dump($_POST)` to see all data that's received and then check if you're using the wrong key.

Comment: Try adding `http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postdata.length);` when setting headers

Comment: Did that Ali...no difference...still responding with array (0)

Comment: Update `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");` to `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");`

Comment: And also try sending POST data in a query string format.

Comment: Tried that - same problem - Array(0) and empty array in post. There must be something simple that I'm missing here...

Comment: Still struggling with this - getting all what is expected in the console but can't parse it - so went back to using JSON - can get the data fields - but don't know how to get at the $_Files element. Shows that there is an object there but not sure how to get at it or save it.